# ¿Cómo insertar un solo resultado de una consulta que arroja varias a una tabla temporal en SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente después de hacer la consulta: 

`use Northwind
go
exec sp_spaceused
go`

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera insertar solo las columnas (`database_name`, `database_size`, `unallocated space`) del primer resultado a una tabla temporal, pero como ven es una consulta con dos resultados, de modo que no he podido hacerlo de la manera tradicional:

`create table #tab_temp
(.....)
insert into 
exec sp_spaceused`

Agradecido por sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, lo que puedes hacer es ver el código del procedimiento almacenado `sp_spaceused` y encontrar el `SELECT` que necesitas.

Lo revisé y modifiqué un poco para que lo puedas usar:

```
USE Northwind;

WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  SUM(CONVERT(bigint,CASE WHEN status & 64 = 0 THEN size ELSE 0 END)) dbsize, 
            SUM(CONVERT(bigint,CASE WHEN status & 64 <> 0 THEN size ELSE 0 END)) logsize 
    FROM dbo.sysfiles
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  SUM(a.total_pages) reservedpages,
            SUM(a.used_pages) usedpages,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    -- XML-Index and FT-Index internal tables are not considered "data", but is part of "index_size"
                    WHEN it.internal_type IN (202,204,211,212,213,214,215,216) THEN 0
                    WHEN a.type <> 1 THEN a.used_pages
                    WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) pages 
    FROM sys.partitions p 
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a 
        ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables it 
        ON p.object_id = it.object_id
)

SELECT  db_name() database_name,
        LTRIM(STR((CONVERT(decimal(15,2),dbsize) + CONVERT(decimal(15,2),logsize)) 
                    * 8192 / 1048576,15,2) + ' MB'),
        LTRIM(STR((CASE WHEN dbsize >= reservedpages THEN
        (CONVERT(decimal(15,2),dbsize) - CONVERT(decimal(15,2),reservedpages)) 
                    * 8192 / 1048576 ELSE 0 END),15,2) + ' MB') [unallocated space]
FROM CTE1 
CROSS JOIN CTE2;
```

De esta forma, puedes crear la tabla temporal e insertar los datos necesarios:

```
Use Northwind;

WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  SUM(CONVERT(bigint,CASE WHEN status & 64 = 0 THEN size ELSE 0 END)) dbsize, 
            SUM(CONVERT(bigint,CASE WHEN status & 64 <> 0 THEN size ELSE 0 END)) logsize 
    FROM dbo.sysfiles
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  SUM(a.total_pages) reservedpages,
            SUM(a.used_pages) usedpages,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    -- XML-Index and FT-Index internal tables are not considered "data", but is part of "index_size"
                    WHEN it.internal_type IN (202,204,211,212,213,214,215,216) THEN 0
                    WHEN a.type <> 1 THEN a.used_pages
                    WHEN p.index_id < 2 THEN a.data_pages
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) pages 
    FROM sys.partitions p 
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a 
        ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables it 
        ON p.object_id = it.object_id
)

SELECT  db_name() database_name,
        LTRIM(STR((CONVERT(decimal(15,2),dbsize) + CONVERT(decimal(15,2),logsize)) 
                    * 8192 / 1048576,15,2) + ' MB'),
        LTRIM(STR((CASE WHEN dbsize >= reservedpages THEN
        (CONVERT(decimal(15,2),dbsize) - CONVERT(decimal(15,2),reservedpages)) 
                    * 8192 / 1048576 ELSE 0 END),15,2) + ' MB') [unallocated space]
INTO #Resultados
FROM CTE1 
CROSS JOIN CTE2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar al resultado anterior, la información de dicho procedimiento la puedes ubicar procedimientos almacenados del master.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que como lo planteas no será posible. Esto solo lo podrías lograr revisando el código de `sp_spaceused` y ejecutando la consulta directamente, o en su caso, ingresando esa consulta a un *Stored Procedure*. El *query* quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
declare 
     @pages bigint
    ,@dbsize bigint
    ,@logsize bigint
    ,@reservedpages  bigint
    ,@usedpages  bigint

select @dbsize = sum(convert(bigint,case when status & 64 = 0 then size else 0 end))
        , @logsize = sum(convert(bigint,case when status & 64 <> 0 then size else 0 end))
        from dbo.sysfiles

    select @reservedpages = sum(a.total_pages),
        @usedpages = sum(a.used_pages),
        @pages = sum(
                CASE
                    -- XML-Index and FT-Index and semantic index internal tables are not considered "data", but is part of "index_size"
                    When it.internal_type IN (202,204,207,211,212,213,214,215,216,221,222,236) Then 0
                    When a.type <> 1 and p.index_id < 2 Then a.used_pages
                    When p.index_id < 2 Then a.data_pages
                    Else 0
                END
            )
    from sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id
        left join sys.internal_tables it on p.object_id = it.object_id

select 
        database_name = db_name(),
        database_size = ltrim(str((convert (dec (15,2),@dbsize) + convert (dec (15,2),@logsize)) 
            * 8192 / 1048576,15,2) + ' MB'),
        'unallocated space' = ltrim(str((case when @dbsize >= @reservedpages then
            (convert (dec (15,2),@dbsize) - convert (dec (15,2),@reservedpages)) 
            * 8192 / 1048576 else 0 end),15,2) + ' MB')
```